# Python on Windows Server - Get user accessing shared file

Tags: python, file, windows-server-2008, shared

I need to find which proccess, user or pc has a certain file open. I can do it manually through the utilities that come with the win server but I would like to script this since I am dealing with hundreds of files.

Any ideas, suggestions please?

Basically a list of the information below:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this info requires some undocumented Win32 APIs.  You could call something like `handle.exe`
from sysinternals which uses them, but I suggest you use the `psutil` module, available from PyPi.  Here is some example code (Py3) I happen to have which lists all the files in use, you should be able to modify that:

```
import psutil

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        flist = proc.get_open_files()
        if flist:
            print(proc.pid,proc.name)
            for nt in flist:
                print("\t",nt.path)

    except psutil.NoSuchProcess as err:
        print("****",err)
```

Note that there is always a chance of a race condition with these kind of queries - you do not know at what point a process opens or closes a file, or even starts and finishes.

PS:  if you are on Python 3, I had some problems installing psutil, but usinging the 2to3 conversion utility on the setup.py fixed the issues.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Python 2.6 and got the psutil package working but I get this error when running the code:

<code>
  File "C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\test_deleteme.py", line 5, in <module>
    flist = proc.get_open_files()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 41, in get_open_files
    return self._platform_impl.get_open_files()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\psutil\_psmswindows.py", line 145, in wrapper
    raise AccessDenied(self.pid, self._process_name)
psutil.error.AccessDenied: (pid=1280)
</code>

Comment: Looks like you are trying to interogate a process to which you don't have access.  Run as administrator?

Comment: Can you please give an example of the "handle.exe from sysinternals" method you mentioned?

Comment: There's no way to avoid AccessDenied for certain processes, even by running the script as Administrator.